# getParametersByPath page size

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

In AWS-SDK for Node.js `getParametersByPath()` SSM method returns paged data, meaning I have to make several calls in a loop. Is there a way to disable pagination or increase page size (beyond 10, which is max for `MaxNumber`parameter) ?

Alternatively, if several calls have to be made - can results be collected into array of Promises to be resolved at once?

Basically, we have about 12 parameters that we need to load on a Lambda startup. Currently getting parameters takes about 2 seconds - because 2 consecutive calls are made. Ideally it has to either be one call or 2 calls made in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question. Let me outline some concepts, AWS design decisions and how I would work around the limitations they impose.

#### 1. AWS Server Side SSM API

All AWS client SDKs, including the AWS-SDK for Node.js, make API calls towards the respective AWS service's REST API, e.g. the API action *GetParametersByPath* of the AWS Systems Manager endpoint [1].

#### 2. Pagination

The AWS APIs usually implement the so called *cursor-based pagination* concept. This type of pagination has other characteristics than *page-based pagination* (i.e. classic offset-limit pagination) - described in several Medium articles [2][3].

One major limitation of cursor-based pagination is: **It doesn’t allow sending parallel requests for different batches.** There is no way to jump for a specific page, it needs to iterate through all the prior pages.

Looking at the pros and cons of each pagination type, the AWS engineers probably made a trade-off in favor of *consistency* at the cost of *performance*.

#### 3. API Limitation

AWS states that the valid range for the *MaxResults* parameter is 1-10. That means, there is no way for a client to extend the page size beyond 10. All SDKs must adhere to that limit when implementing pagination. Disabling pagination [4] has the only effect of returning a single page of up to 10 items.

#### 4. Possible Workarounds

1. You could sync the SSM API results to a custom DynamoDB table and query DynamoDB instead of SSM. If this solution is viable depends on several characteristics, e.g. consistency requirements, how often SSM parameters are changing and confidentiality of SSM parameter values (or which parameter attributes are read by the Lambda function).
2. You could send concurrent requests to the API if you split the set of expected results properly and use the ParameterFilters API parameter [1]. You can split by following keys: `tag:.+|Name|Type|KeyId|Path|Label|Tier|DataType` using the `BeginsWith` or `Equals` option. [5]

   **This solution requires that you can make assumptions about the results you expect to receive.** You must ensure that a particular subset does not contain more than 10 entries.  If there are e.g. max. 10 SSM parameters per department, you could do the following: Send one request via *getParametersByPath()* per department, specifying `MaxResults=10` and `Path=/department/<name>` or `ParameterFilters=[{Key=tag:department,Option=Equals,Values=["<name>"]}]`. These department-specific requests could be sent concurrently.

Workaround 2 could be considered the "two concurrent requests" approach you mentioned in the question and workaround 1 is the "one single request" approach. Workarounds require to either drop the consistency property or making assumptions about the data partitioning.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParametersByPath.html#systemsmanager-GetParametersByPath-request-NextToken
[2] https://medium.com/innomizetech/how-to-build-an-api-with-aws-lambda-to-paginate-data-using-serverless-41c4b6b676a4
[3] https://medium.com/swlh/paginating-requests-in-apis-d4883d4c1c4c
[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html#cli-usage-pagination-serverside
[5] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_ParameterStringFilter.html#systemsmanager-Type-ParameterStringFilter-Option

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Even though this answer doesn't provide conclusive solution I will accept it (and reward the bounty when allowed) because it pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to give you a simple answer for this and a question I've had to solve for a few times:

> Alternatively, if several calls have to be made - can results be collected into array of Promises to be resolved at once?

Yes, and here's how -

```js
const { SSM } = require('aws-sdk');
const ssm = new SSM();

function getSSMStuff(path, memo = [], nextToken) {
  return ssm
.getParametersByPath({ Path: path, WithDecryption: true, Recursive: true, NextToken: nextToken, MaxResults: 10 })
.promise()
.then(({ Parameters, NextToken }) => {
  const newMemo = memo.concat(Parameters);
  return NextToken ? getSSMStuff(path, newMemo, NextToken) : newMemo;
});
}
```

if you invoke that with a path, it'll recursively call itself to get all parameters in that path, finally resolving to an array of complete parameters. Obviously, you should do your own flavor of error handling, but that's the gist.

Comment: Thanks. This would work for us if we knew names of parameters in advance and could use `getParameters()`. The problem is this is a generic package used by other code and the input it gets is parameters path, to retrieve recursively all parameters within given path via `getParametersByPath()`

Comment: No worries, I modified my solution to be more tailored to your specific needs.

Comment: But this is back to the original problem - we now need several consecutive blocking calls to retrieve all parameters.

Comment: Hey guys, if I am not missing something then it is simply not possible to avoid consecutive calls because of the way the API is designed.

Comment: I was hoping for some workaround, and it looks like I will have to go with your solution @MartinLöper

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is achievable. I gathered 92 parameters with the below logic (it is coded in java, but can be used as a reference) -

```
 //initialize
 List<Parameter> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
 String nextToken = null;
               
 //logic
 do {
      GetParametersByPathRequest request = new GetParametersByPathRequest();
      request.setWithDecryption(true);
      request.setPath("......");
      request.setRecursive(true);
      request.setNextToken(nextToken);
      GetParametersByPathResult parametersByPathResult = source.getParametersByPath(request);
      nextToken = parametersByPathResult.getNextToken();
      parameters.addAll(parametersByPathResult.getParameters());
      }  while(nextToken!=null);
```